# How to listen for URL changes from a React App embedded using script tags with source as the compiled javascript files generated after build?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have developed a chat widget using React and embedded it (using script tags with source as the compiled javascript files generated after build) on another website which is also build with React. I add the script tag to my websites `index.html`. The chat widget is displayed successfully. I want the chat component to re-render everytime the URL on my website changes. I used `useHistory` hook in chat widget application to listen for history changes but it does not work as the website itself uses react-router.

Comment: No, the chat widget which is embedded on the webapp

Comment: You can use Window.location.href/pathname to compare